# If $f(x) \in L^2([0,1])$, then $g(x)=|f(x)|^{x+1} \in L^1([0,1])$.

Tags: measure-theory

Here $L^p([0,1])$ are spaces with respect to the Lebesgue measure m.

I have shown that with this condition $f(x)$ is finite a.e. I was trying to use the Holder inequality somewhere but I did not get anywhere.

Comment: Simpler. Note that $L^2([0,1]) \subset L^1([0,1])$, so $\lvert f\rvert \in L^1([0,1])$ and $\lvert f\rvert^2 \in L^1([0,1])$.

Comment: $$g\leqslant\max\{|f|,|f|^2\}\leqslant1+|f|^2$$

Comment: Since $L^2([0,1]) \subset L^1([0,1])$, so $|f| \in L^1([0,1])$. Now take to subset $E_1=\lbrace x \; ; \; |f(x)| \leq 1 \rbrace$ and $E_2=\lbrace x \; ; \; |f(x)| >1 \rbrace$. So $$\int |g(x)|=\int_{E_1} |f(x)|^x |f(x)| +\int_{E_2} |f(x)|^x |f(x)|$$. But on $E_1$ we have that $|f(x)|^x|f(x)| \leq |f|^2$, therefore, $$\int_{E_1} |g(x)| \leq \int_{E_1} |f|^2 \leq \infty$$. On $E_2$, $|f|^{2x} < |f|^2$, which implies that $f(x)^x\in L^2([0,1]), therefore $$\int_{E_2} |g(x)| =\int_{E_2} |f(x)|^x|f(x)| \leq ||f(x)^x||_{L^2} ||f||_{L^2} < \infty$. Where the last inequality is Schwartz's inequality.